# MSchart label inside chart area

Tags: mschart

[image]

Can somebody please tell me how can i show the Total Collection on MSChart

Comment: I have got the answer in email which is incomplete , but i can't see it here, why ? help please.

Comment: The mail you received is about an answer that has been deleted by owner (I can see it because I have more than 10K points).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`chart.Annotations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456725.aspx) property to get a similar result.

For example with the following code (located after filling the chart):

```
var ann = new RectangleAnnotation();
ann.Text = "Total Collection" + Environment.NewLine + "250 Billion";
ann.IsMultiline = true;
ann.AxisX = this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
ann.AxisY = this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
ann.AnchorX = 9;  // as you can see from the image below,
ann.AnchorY = 41; // these values are inside the range

// add the annotation to the chart annotations list
this.chart1.Annotations.Add(ann);
```

I got the following result:

[image]

N.B.:
there are a lot of annotations types (`CalloutAnnotation`, `EllipseAnnotation`...) and they have a lot of properties to change styles and behaviors. You can even set a property to allow annotation moving (i.e. `AllowMoving=true`).

Have a look to annotation properties through intellisense or MSDN.

Comment: @codery2k: did you add the annotation to the chart.Annotations collection ? (my updated code now show how...) Also, are you sure you have selected valid AnchorX and AnchorY values? (they must be in the visible range)

Comment: Yea I did it too, and I have selected valid X and Y axis, but still no result. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can set the property `IsDockedInsideChartArea` to `true`. You will also need to specify which ChartArea the legend is docked to, and set the position property to `Auto`.

```
legend.IsDockedInsideChartArea = true;
legend.DockedToChartArea = "ChartArea1";
```

There are more information about this and other legend properties [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.legend.isdockedinsidechartarea.aspx).